# Certain Korean characters are showing up as question marks/diamonds when scraping, how can I fix this?

Tags: python, encoding, beautifulsoup

I am scraping some text in Korean and for the most part 99.9% of the characters show up but the rest look like below.

```
�Z
```

For example, it should be scraping "고소를해줫어", but in my output it's giving me "고소를해�Z어".

I know this is an encoding issue, I just do not know how I can fix that. I've read that you can use `.encode('utf-8')` but that did not solve it.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Full code added for context (beginner programmer so please excuse the messy code!):

```
import bs4 as bs
import requests

raw_link = input("Enter the article's URL: ")
article_id = raw_link[26:40]
source = "http://comm.news.nate.com/Comment/ArticleComment/list?artc_sq=" + article_id + "&prebest=0&order=O&mid=n1008&domain=&argList=0"
headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_11_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/53.0.2785.143 Safari/537.36'}
r = requests.get(source, headers = headers)
html = r.text
soup = bs.BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

upvotes = []
downvotes = []
comment_list = []
user_list = []
numbered_list = [1., 2., 3., 4., 5., 6., 7., 8., 9., 10., 11., 12., 13., 14., 15., 16., 17., 18., 19., 20.]
raw_numbered_list = list(map(int, numbered_list))

for url in soup.select('strong[name*="cmt_o_cnt_"]')[3:]:
    raw_numbers_up = url.text.strip()
    upvotes.append(raw_numbers_up)

for url in soup.select('strong[name*="cmt_x_cnt_"]')[3:]:
    raw_numbers_down = url.text.strip()
    downvotes.append(raw_numbers_down)

for url in soup.find_all('dd', class_="usertxt")[3:]:
    comments = url.text.strip()
    comment_list.append(comments)

for url in soup.find_all('span', {'class':['nameui', 't']})[3:]:
    user_id = url.text.strip()
    user_list.append(user_id)

results = list(zip(raw_numbered_list, upvotes, downvotes, user_list, comment_list))
for number, upvote, downvote, user, comment in results:
    replies = ("\n{}. [+{}, -{}] {}:\n{}".format(number, upvote, downvote, user, comment))
    print(replies)
```

**EDIT 1:** I've tested the same code on my laptop and I'm still running into the same issue! If anyone else wants to check if they get the same issue, change the entire string in the `source` variable near the top of the code to `"http://comm.news.nate.com/Comment/ArticleComment/list?artc_sq=20170818n20195&prebest=0&order=O&mid=n1008&domain=&argList=0"` and see if you get it.

**EDIT 2:** Could it possibly be the `user-agent` that I'm using?

**EDIT 3:** I'm almost certain now it's a `euc-kr` and `utf-8` issue. The page I'm scraping from is encoded in `euc-kr` so I get a feeling there's something in my code that is conflicting with how the text is being read.

**EDIT: 4** I ran the `chardet` module using the page I am scraping from and it said the encoding is `cp949`, so not `euc-kr` as I had thought. Also, tested the code in Spyder instead of PyCharm: same issue occurs.

Comment: Try `latin-1`? `.encode('latin-1')`

Comment: please provide more context and a sample of your code

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ That didn't work unfortunately. "UnicodeEncodeError: 'latin-1' codec can't encode characters in position 26-27: ordinal not in range(256)"

Comment: @damians I've added my code to the OP, let me know what else you need to know. Thanks!

Comment: Try saving replies to a file. Maybe there is a problem with terminal encoding.

Comment: OR use utf-8 compatible terminal IDEs like Spyder.

Comment: @Rahul I'm using PyCharm and my file encoding is set to UTF-8 by default. Should I still try out Spyder?

Comment: What's wrong in trying? I tried the string you provided and it prints ok in spyder ide(Ipython).

Comment: @Rahul Just installed Spyder and tested out the code but the same characters still show up.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like a weird error. As most of the HANGUL characters are correctly displayed, it cannot be a simple encoding problem. What looks even more strange is that your example replaces the SYLLABLE JWEOS ('줫' U+C92B) with the REPLACEMENT CHARACTER ('�') *followed by the LATIN CAPITAL LETTER Z ('Z' U+005A)*. And I cannot imagine where that `Z` can come from, none of the encodings I know can convert 0xc92b in anything followed with 0x5a.

I can only imagine data corruption.

Comment: As in a local data corruption issue? I think you may be correct. Wondering if it would show up correctly on a computer other than my own. I'll test it out.

Comment: I am still getting the same error on my laptop. Not sure what it could be at this point.

Comment: @jrmymj: can you make sure that the data sent by the server is correct?

Comment: How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Save the scraped page and examine it.